# Vagrant Centos 6 box - MySQL - command not found

Tags: mysql, vagrant, centos6

I am using a Centos 6 image with MySQL installed in it.

When I ssh in the machine I can use the command to run a SQL script in this

`mysql -u root < db.sql`, 
but when I try to `vagrant reload --provision`, config.vm.provision :shell, inline:

`mysql -u root < /home/vagrant/files/db.sql` gets an error

> *default: /tmp/vagrant-shell: line 1: mysql: command not found*

Comment: so do you try to access the MySQL when you log onto Centos, after `vagrant reload --provision`?

Comment: @niklaz first time I try to bring up the instance with the line "config.vm.provision :shell, inline: mysql -u root < /home/vagrant/files/db.sql " in my vagrantfile file and I receive the mysql command not found. After that, the vm is up, but without that configuration for mysql, and I ssh into it with "vagrant ssh" and run inside the vm the msyql command and it works.

So, outside the vm sais mysql is a command not found, and inside the vm mysql command works.

Comment: Nevermind, I found the problem. mysql executable wasn't in any folder like /usr/bin, /bin or /usr/sbin/bin and from outside vm it wasn't reachable.